# Ajax callbacks not working with Rails 3.0.5 and jQuery 1.5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I've got ajax pagination working with the [Kaminari gem](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) on my website but I'm having difficulty getting ajax callbacks working

I'm using jquery-1.5.1, rails 3.0.5 and I have the latest rails.js file

My `podcasts.html.haml` looks as follows

```
#paginator
  = paginate @podcasts, :remote => true

#podcasts
  = render @podcasts
```

My index.js.erb file looks like this:

```
$('#podcasts').html('<%= escape_javascript render(@podcasts) %>');
$('#paginator').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@podcasts, :remote => true).to_s) %>');
```

The pagination side of things works fine, and the pages do indeed load via ajax but I want to do some ajax callbacks and I just can't figure out how to get this working.

I've tried adding numerous variations of the following code to my application.js file but with no success at all:

```
$('#paginator a').bind('ajax:success', function(data, status, xhr) {alert("success!");})
```

I would expect the code above to fire off an alert once the ajax stuff has finished. Nothing is happening though.

Anyone got any ideas?

### PS

The paginate method above, is from the [Kaminari gem](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) and it creates the following html:

```
<div id="paginator">
  <nav class="pagination">
    <a href="/podcasts" data-remote="true">Page 1</a>
    <a href="/podcasts?page=2" data-remote="true">Page 2</a>
    <a href="/podcasts?page=3" data-remote="true">Page 3</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: I have same problem, it seems like `$('#paginator').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@podcasts, :remote => true).to_s) %>');` this line causes callback to stop. If you change it to `.html` to `.append` it gives callback ..but unfortunately with duplication pagination links. Did you solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to follow exactly your code, but I made a simple test (jquery 1.5.1, rails 3.0.5), and it works for me:

**ajax_controller.rb**

```
class AjaxController < ApplicationController
  def get_data
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { sleep 1; render :json => "ajax value" }
    end
  end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "get_data", get_data_path, :remote => true, :id => 'request' %>

<div id="response">
</div>

<%= javascript_tag do %>
    $("#response").html("default value");

    $("#request").bind("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
        $("#response").html(data);
    });
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
    get "ajax/index"
    get "ajax/get_data", :as => "get_data"
```

I hope this help.

Comment: hey @plang, thanks for that, I will get a chance to try it out later on tonight but the advice looks good, and makes sense so I think I can solve the problem with it. Thanks again, cheers