# Ajax Call back Doesnt respond

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have same problem as this question [Ajax callbacks not working with Rails 3.0.5 and jQuery 1.5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5169628/3786657). I din't understand the answer to it but. I have found what is causing problem but not sure why it is and how to solve it. I am using **Kaminari** gem.

Please help me out.

In my **VIEW:**

```
<div id="paginator">
  <%= paginate @user, params: {id: nil, pgsz: 20}, remote: true %>
</div>
```

In my **Controller** :

```
  @user = Kaminari.paginate_array(@properties, total_count: @search_result.total_count).page(@pg).per(@pgsz)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
    end
```

In MY **Show.js.erb**

```
$('#list').html("<%=j (render 'search_result_list') %>");
$('#paginator').html("<%=j (paginate(@user, params: {id: nil, pgsz: 20}, remote: true).to_s) %>");
```

In my another **JS** file where i monitor the ajax

```
$('#paginator')
.on("ajax:send",  function () {
  // Run a spinner
  console.log("=====BEfore SEND");
})
.on("ajax:complete",  function (e, data, status, xhr) {
  // Stop the spinner
  console.log("=====Afte SEND");
})
```

So i figured out that `$('#paginator').html("<%=j (paginate(@user, params: {id: nil, pgsz: 20}, remote: true).to_s) %>");` this line is causing not to callback for either `ajax:successs or ajax:complete`. But if i modify `$('#paginator').html`**to** `$('#paginator').append` callback happens but its not what i need.

**UPDATE**:

Just found that its not only`$('#paginator').html("<%=j (paginate(@user, params: {id: nil, pgsz: 20}, remote: true).to_s) %>");` which is causing but if i just modify it to `$('#paginator').html("Hey");` also causes no callback .

Any idea why its happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order of the `format` in your controller.

```
@user = Kaminari.paginate_array(@properties, total_count: @search_result.total_count).page(@pg).per(@pgsz)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
```

I had the similar issue, and adding `format.js` at the end helped. I also had `format.json` after html one, not sure if you need this or not.